# How to use fetch to post with content-type of application/json

Tags: json, node.js, cors, fetch

I have a react application that does a fetch call to an API as follows:

```
 postForm(state) {
    var formData = state.formData;
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/V0.1/formSubmit', {method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: JSON.stringify(formData)})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson);
      return null;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

however, it gets blocked by CORS as the spec states that application/json is non-standard content type.

However, I'm not sure how I can modify my fetch call to perform the required pre-flight request to get it to allow application/json.

The API call is:

```
app.post("/api/v0.1/formSubmit", function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  var formData=req.body;
  console.log(formData);
  res.status(200).json(formData);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before defining your routing. declare

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var oneof = false;
        if(req.headers.origin) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
            oneof = true;
        }
        if(req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
            oneof = true;
        }
        if(req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
            oneof = true;
        }
        if(oneof) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        }

        // intercept OPTIONS method
        if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
            res.send(200);
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    });
```

In CORS, the request is checked for available methods on server. i.e. in **OPTIONS** request. When you get the successful response, you will able to send request.

You can enable CORS for specific pages also. study here https://github.com/expressjs/cors